# Local notification in realme when swipe up local notification not show again, any else with my code?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, localnotification

Local notification is not shown again in REALME when I swipe up to clear notification, but swipe right and left notification show again and normal, any else with my code? I try to make id different but it's not working.

Here is my code :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    protected void onOrderChanged(OrderDataModel dm) {

        String status = "Status: " + dm.getOrderStatus();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH; //Important for heads-up notification
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("OrderMessage")
                .setContentText("OrderId: " + dm.getOrderId() + "\n" + status + "\n" + dm.getNote())
                .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE) //Important for heads-up notification
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX); //Important for heads-up notification

        Notification buildNotification = mBuilder.build();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(001, buildNotification);

        if (dm.getOrderStatus().equals("P") || dm.getOrderStatus().equals("M"))
            dispatchClientStockRequest(this._user.getUserId());

    }
```